# gcloud on Windows 10 CommandLoadFailure: not loading gcloud.container: AddCustomJsonEnumMapping() got an unexpected keyword argument 'package'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, windows-10, gcloud

Google Cloud SDK is Installed correctly but unable to run gcloud command at all on Windows 10. Error is the same in both powershell and command prompt with Administrative rights.

gcloud compute/config/setting things works surprisingly fine and I can list instances/set things.

only commands that result with these error messages are typing "gcloud" with no additional parameters, or enever a wrong command sequence is typed (like "gcloud foe" also results in the same error message).

**Following error message below:**

```
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\gcloud\gcloud.py", line 194, in main
    _cli.Execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 607, in Execute
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse\__init__.py", line 1703, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse\__init__.py", line 1735, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse\__init__.py", line 1952, in _parse_known_args
    self.error(_('too few arguments'))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 166, in error
    alternates = cli_generator.ReplicateCommandPathForAllOtherTracks(
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\usage_text.py", line 396, in ShortHelpText
    if arg.required:
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 936, in LoadAllSubElements
    for name, info in src.iteritems():
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 970, in LoadSubElement
    Returns:
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 769, in __init__
    return self.ai.flag_args + self.ai.ancestor_flag_args
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 681, in _GetModuleFromPath
    Returns:
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\container\commands\__init__.py", line 10, in 
    from googlecloudsdk.container.lib import api_adapter
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\container\lib\api_adapter.py", line 7, in 
    from googlecloudapis.container import v1 as container_v1
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudapis\container\v1\__init__.py", line 7, in 
    from googlecloudapis.container.v1.container_v1_client import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudapis\container\v1\container_v1_client.py", line 5, in 
    from googlecloudapis.container.v1 import container_v1_messages as messages
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudapis\container\v1\container_v1_messages.py", line 486, in 
    package=u'container')
CommandLoadFailure: Problem loading gcloud.container: AddCustomJsonEnumMapping() got an unexpected keyword argument 'package'.
```

I believe it is interpreted by Python2.7.9 as its path is included in the system file path and I can successfully run other python scripts on this machine.

**Output of gcloud info**

```
Google Cloud SDK [0.9.69]

Platform: [Windows, x86_64]
Python Version: [2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]]
Site Packages: [Disabled]

Installation Root: [C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  core: [2015.07.10]
  app-engine-python: [1.9.23]
  bq-win: [2.0.18]
  app-engine-python-extras: [1.9.21]
  core-win: [2015.06.02]
  app: [2015.07.10]
  gcloud: [2015.07.10]
  windows-ssh-tools: [2015.06.02]
  gcutil-msg: [2015.07.02]
  gsutil: [4.13]
  bq: [2.0.18]
  preview: [2015.07.10]
  gsutil-win: [4.12]
System PATH: [C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\bin\sdk;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [True]

Installation Properties: [C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\properties]
User Config Directory: [c:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\gcloud]
User Properties: [c:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\properties]
Current Workspace: [None]
Workspace Config Directory: [None]
Workspace Properties: [None]

Account: [user@domain.com]
Project: [None]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    account: [user@domain.com]
    disable_usage_reporting: [True]

Logs Directory: [c:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs]
Last Log File: [c:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\2015.07.24\01.00.51.385000.log]
```

Anyone else experienced this / any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of python are you using? Are you able to run 'gcloud info'? If so, can you please provide its output (removing any personal data). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Vilas, I have I believe it is interpreted by Python2.7.9, and I have added output of gcloud info as requested.

Comment: Check the logs (last lines of gcloud info output) to see if there's more info there?

Comment: @Daniel, which command caused the error? What are the steps required to reproduce it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, 
@Nick - the error above is from the log.

Comment: @Vilas, this is for "gcloud" without additional parameters, and also "gcloud help" produces these error message or whenever you write something with wrong syntax "gcloud foe".

Comment: @Daniel, its very strange that gcloud info works while gcloud and gcloud help result in errors. Your installation may have been corrupted somehow. Can you try a separate fresh installation using the alternative archive method: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/#install-archive ? Thank you and sorry about the delayed response.

Comment: I second the advice to get a clean install, which will remove all previous gcloud components from your system. Check if the error persists at that point.

Comment: Any update on this question? Did a clean install manage to clear it up?

Comment: Hi, I have removed all gcloud components and reinstalled, issue was not resolved. Issue resolved only after reinstalling the OS.

Thank you guys.